# Error generating .exe with py2exe

Tags: python-2.7, exe, py2exe, ioerror

I'm genetating a .exe with python and when i try to run it, a .log is generated with the following lines:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cuasimodo.py", line 1077, in 
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'index.json'

obviously index.json is a file of my program which is in the same file as the rest, but it's having some problems finding it.
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file without specifying the full path, it is opened from the current working directory. It is better to specify the full path.

See ["You want to know WHERE your .exe is"](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WhereAmI).

Comment: yea but index.json its in the current working directory, so how can't it be opened?

Comment: Maybe the working directory is not what you think it is. Or the file is not where you think it is. Or there is some other bug.

Comment: @user2381651 If you are running the program under the Program Files folder on Windows, you may be suffering from folder virtualization.